# Chart Duplicates because of useEffect re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, lightweight-charts

I have a parent component which I'm using to pass props (i.e `backgroundColor`) to child component( `<LivePortfolioGraph />`).

In my child component I have a dependency array that re-renders every time color is changed from parent i.e (`props.backgroundColor`).

Now i don't want want to create a new graph on every render, if chart exist just apply color options.

Really appreciate any help! Thanks.

***Parent Component***

```
    const Main = (props) => {
    
      const [backgroundColor, setbackgroundColor] = useState('#141d27');
    
     const g = useRef(null);
    
    return (
    
     <div ref={g} className="FinancialChartIntro" >
    
        <LivePortfolioGraph g={g} backgroundColor={backgroundColor} />
    
        </div> 
    
    )
}
```

***Child Component***

```
const  LivePortfolioGraph = (props) => {

const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);


useEffect( ()=> {

const handleStyle = _debounce(() => { chart.applyOptions({layout: {backgroundColor:props.backgroundColor  } }); }, 100)

window.addEventListener("input", handleStyle); 


const chart = createChart(props.g.current, options );


// Clean Up
return () => {


window.removeEventListener('input', handleStyle);

}



}, [props.backgroundColor])
```

[image: First Render]

[image: When I change color, another graph shows up with the previous defaultValue]

[image: Element Created]

***UPDATE***
I have found a hacky way to remove child nodes( chart dups). It slows down the page like crazy I dont wanna even  use it. STILL TRYING to find another solution.

> ```
> > if(props.g.current.childNodes.length > 2) {
> > props.g.current.removeChild(props.g.current.childNodes[2])  }
> ```

Comment: I believe we'll need more code to be able to help with this. Can you also include a running minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the single `useEffect` hook is doing "too much" work. Move the `chart` value into a React ref and use the effect hook to update the color/styling.

```
const  LivePortfolioGraph = (props) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = React.useState(0);

  const chart = React.useRef(createChart(props.g.current, options);

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    const handleStyle = _debounce(() => {
      chart.current.applyOptions({
        layout: {
          backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
        },
      });
    }, 100);

    window.addEventListener("input", handleStyle); 
    // Clean Up
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('input', handleStyle);
    }
}, [props.backgroundColor]);
```

Comment: OK your direction is definitely more sensible and right however, I'm still getting other charts duplicated but only the first graph color changes

Comment: @Ibra I wasn't aware of other charts. Can you provide a more comprehensive code example in your question? If possible can you create and share a *running& codesandbox demo that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure how to reproduce a running sanbox(that's a qood stackoverflow question!). Sorry for the confusion but there is only one chart (Liveportfoliograpgh)  however whenever I change the color the chart redraws again underneath it. I'll edit my question to show a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Just perform a check to see if the chart has already be instantiated.

Here is a snippet of a hook I created to setup the chart `useSetupChart`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!chartContainerRef.current || chart) return;

    setChart(createChart(chartContainerRef.current));
  }, [chartContainerRef.current, chart]);
```