# Component duplicates when dispatching an action via redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, lightweight-charts

So I have written some code to display a chart and I have also written a function which will allow me to change the timeframe of the chart. However, when this function is invoked, a duplicate chart pops up.

Here is the **Chart.js**

```
let chartProperties = {
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    timeScale: {
        timeVisible: true,
        secondsVisible: false
    }
}

const Chart = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const lightweightChart = createChart(document.body, chartProperties);
    const candleSeries = lightweightChart.addCandlestickSeries();

    const fetchData = () => {
        axios.get(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&limit=1000`)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(data => {
                const candlestickData = data.map(d => {
                    return { time: d[0] / 1000, open: parseFloat(d[1]), high: parseFloat(d[2]), low: parseFloat(d[3]), close: parseFloat(d[4]) }
                });
                candleSeries.setData(candlestickData);
            }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        chartData: state.chartOptionsReducer
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Chart);
```

Here is the action creator **chartActions.js**

```
export const changeTimeframe = (timeframe) => {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_TIMEFRAME',
        payload: {
            timeframe: timeframe
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the reducer **chartOptionsReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
    symbol: 'BTCUSDT',
    timeframe: '4h'
}

const chartOptionsReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_TIMEFRAME') {
        let newTimeframe = action.payload.timeframe
        return {
            ...state,
            timeframe: newTimeframe
        }
    } else {
        return state;
    }
}

export default chartOptionsReducer;
```

And finally this is where the action gets called from **OptionsColumn.js**

```
const OptionColumn = (props) => {

    const handleTimeframe = (timeframe) => {
        props.changeTimeframe(timeframe)
    }

    return (
        <Menu
            label="Timeframe"
            items={[
                { label: '1m', onClick: () => { handleTimeframe('1m') } },
                { label: '4h', onClick: () => { handleTimeframe('4h') } },
            ]}
        />
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        changeTimeframe: (timeframe) => { dispatch(changeTimeframe(timeframe)) }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OptionColumn);
```

I think the issue may be coming from this line in **Chart.js** though i'm not sure, and i'm also not sure how to avoid it:

```
const lightweightChart = createChart(document.body, chartProperties);
```

**BONUS ISSUE:** Anybody who is familiar with the *lightweightChart* package, is there a way to display the chart within a container instead of document.body? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart Duplicates because of useEffect re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67293077/chart-duplicates-because-of-useeffect-re-render)

Answer (score 0):

In React, the component will re-render under certain conditions which include **props** changes.

This code bellow will re-run whenever the **Chart.js** re-render (which it will create new chart targeting `document.body` every time)

```
const lightweightChart = createChart(document.body, chartProperties);
```

Put it in your `useEffect` with your `fetchData()` call

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it within the first argument of the `useEffect` hook and I was hit with this error: `Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined.` So I tried it as the second argument, and it continued to duplicate.

Comment: I now have another issue. Whenever the component re-renders, so does the bundle.js and bundle.js.map in the network tab. The size of the resources loaded by the page reaches over 1000MB very quickly. Why is this happening?